# How to setup starting height and width layout for your android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Is it possible to start your application and let it run on a popup window rather then the entire screen?

PS: My app is designed to work with tablets and with min sdk = 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully did this on sdk 8.

In your manifest, declare the home activity to have the theme.dialog

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="TestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> <!-- hover the activity -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Now when you set the content view of this activity to the layout you defined... in my case just the main.xml

The layout will show up inside a dialog.

Now if you have a large app just set this theme to all of your activities and it should do the trick.

Comment: just SUPER NICE, i didnt think it was that easy and i was kind of struggling finding answers in the official google tutorials and resources for developers.
Thanks josh :)